# In Rails how do I access a server-side rendered React component as HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, recharts

### Context

I am trying to convert a React component to a PNG so that I can attach it to an email in the Rails mailer. The component is a pie [Rechart](https://github.com/recharts/recharts).

I would like to do this all in Rails and not use a Node.js server solution the uses something like [repng](https://github.com/jxnblk/repng) to convert the component into a PNG.

Rechart loads the chart component as an SVG, so I can access the SVG and use something like [Mini-Magic](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#usage) to convert it is a PNG.

### The problem

How to server-side load the React component as HTML in order to access the SVG for conversion.

To server-side load the component in Rails we can do [what react-rails suggests](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#server-side-rendering):

In the view

```
<%= react_component('HelloMessage', {name: 'John'}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

or in the controller

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
    render component: 'TodoList', props: { todos: @todos }, tag: 'span', class: 'todo'
  end
end
```

I would like to do something like what [this posts suggests](https://css-tricks.com/server-side-react-rendering) in using [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html).

```
// Renders our Hello component into an HTML string
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Hello />);
```

I would need to do the equivalent but in Ruby in the Rails mailer. How can I access the server-side rendered component as HTML?

EDIT:

sig's answer is right in that it allows you to access the HTML for the controller instance, this worked for me:

```
controller_instance = ComponentsController.new()
html_string = controller_instance.render_to_string(:action => "index", :layout => false)
```

However, the `html_string` output is:

```
"<div data-react-class=\"personnel/TrainingStatusChart\" data-react-props=\"{&quot;metaData&quot;:{&quot;currentPage&quot;:1,&quot;scopedCount&quot;:23,&quot;statusGreyCount&quot;:15,&quot;statusHighCount&quot;:5,&quot;statusLowCount&quot;:2,&quot;statusMediumCount&quot;:1,&quot;totalCount&quot;:23,&quot;totalPages&quot;:1,&quot;unscopedCount&quot;:23},&quot;prerender&quot;:true}\"></div>\n"
```

It's the React component with all the props going into it. Pre-rendering the React component does not compile it into HTML on the server-side. For this reason it is not possible to access the SVG within the React component for conversion to PNG. [This article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/server-side-rendering-react-with-rails-using-puppeteer-cf5ec2697e88/) puts it as follows:

> This prerendering process does not have access to the window or document so it does not load runtime JavaScript or CSS.

I'm still convinced that this must be possible. Perhaps somehow using Capybara with Headless Chrome to render the React component. I haven't been able to find an example implementation of this however.

Comment: The reason it's not rendering the whole component is because `react_component()` doesn't actually render the component on the server (because it's not doing SSR). `react_component()` only renders the minimal necessary elements on the server so that it can then render the components on the client side. Apologies if this was obvious, but just wanted to make sure everyone's on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `render_to_string` method of controller:

```
controller_instance = ActionController::Base.new()  
#or
controller_instance = ApplicationController.new()

html_string = controller_instance.render_to_string template: 'path_to_file'
```

It accepts the same parameters as `render`. More info https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string